# Is it possible to pass a class method reference to a njit function?

Tags: python, class, reference, numba

I tried to improve the computation time of some of my code. So I use the `njit` decorator of `numba` module to do that. In this example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass, jit, njit
from numba import int32, float64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

spec = [('V_init' ,float64),
        ('a' ,float64),
        ('b' ,float64),
        ('g',float64),
        ('dt' ,float64),
        ('NbODEs',int32),
        ('dydx' ,float64[:]),
        ('time' ,float64[:]),
        ('V' ,float64[:]),
        ('W' ,float64[:]),
        ('y'    ,float64[:]) ]

@jitclass(spec, )
class FHNfunc:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.V_init = .04
        self.a= 0.25
        self.b=0.001
        self.g = 0.003
        self.dt = .01
        self.NbODEs = 2
        self.dydx    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )
        self.y    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )

    def Eul(self,):
        self.deriv()
        self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt)

    def deriv(self,):
        self.dydx[0]= self.V_init - self.y[0] *(self.a-(self.y[0]))*(1-(self.y[0]))-self.y[1]
        self.dydx[1]= self.b * self.y[0] - self.g * self.y[1]
        return



@njit(fastmath=True)
def solve1(FH1,FHEuler,tp):
    V = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    W = np.zeros(len(tp), )

    for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
        FHEuler
        V[idx] = FH1.y[0]
        W[idx] = FH1.y[1]
    return V,W


if __name__ == "__main__":

    FH1 = FHNfunc()
    FHEuler = FH1.Eul

    dt = .01
    tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

    t0 = time.time()
    [V1,W1] = solve1(FH1,FHEuler,tp)
    print(time.time()- t0)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(tp,V1)
    plt.plot(tp,W1)
    plt.show()
```

I would like to pass a reference to a class method named `FHEuler = FH1.Eul`, but it crashes and gives me this error

```
This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 1: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'method'>
```

So is it possible to pass a reference to a njit function? or does it exist a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numba can not handle the function as argument. An alternative way is to compile the function before and than use an inner function to handle the other arguments and return the inner function with compiled input function ran inside it. Try this please:

```
def solve1(FH1,FHEuler,tp):
    FHEuler_f = njit(FHEuler)
    @njit(fastmath=True)
    def inner(FH1_x, tp_x):
        V = np.zeros(len(tp_x), )
        W = np.zeros(len(tp_x), )
        for idx, t in enumerate(tp_x):
            FHEuler_f
            V[idx] = FH1_x.y[0]
            W[idx] = FH1_x.y[1]
        return V,W
    return inner(FH1, tp)
```

Passing function might not be necessary. This one looks work

```
@njit(fastmath=True)
def solve1(FH1,tp):
    FHEuler = FH1.Eul
    V = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    W = np.zeros(len(tp), )

    for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
        FHEuler()
        V[idx] = FH1.y[0]
        W[idx] = FH1.y[1]
    return V,W
```

Comment: That is not working. If I do that, `FH1.Eul()` is executed once when `FHEuler = FH1.Eul()` is called, but it is not executed anymore in the `solve1` function.

Comment: @ymmx thank you the answer has been edited, please try again

Comment: This answer  did not give me any erros but the outputs are just zeros. It is like the Eul function was never called

Comment: @ymmx That may not be a problem of numba. It seems for me that what your Eul function did `self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt)` looks like `y=y0+0*something`, where `y0=0` defined by `self.y=np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )`, which is `0+0*something` and is still 0. My guess is you may want to modify this function

Comment: @ymmx actually, I think you do not need to pass that Eul method, as you already pass the class. You may try my second updates, after modifying Eul method properly

Comment: If I don't use numba at all, the output are changing. Before calling `self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt)`, I call `self.deriv()` which modifies the values of `self.dydx` according to ODEs. How do you set the `FHEuler` in the `__name__`? I did `FHEuler = FH1.Eul` but it is maybe not like that.

Comment: I don't want to call directly the `Eul()` because at the end I will be able to choose between different solver (mid point, RK4 ...) I would like to pass a reference to those function so that the solve1 will not need to be modified each time I want change of solver